# Como sincronizar banco de dados mysql (backup de segurança)

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, backup

Eu tenho um site de hospeda arquivos, (servidor de arquivos), eu sincronizo os arquivos com outro servidor.. em caso de acontecer alguma coisa tenho uma copia de todos os arquivos.. Mas tem alguma forma de sempre salvar um copia do banco dados automaticamente ? sempre eu precisar eu ir no *phpmyadmin* e fazer exportar as tabelas ?

Os arquivos, são sincronizados automaticamente por um *CRON*, tem como fazer o mesmo ou algo parecido com *mysql* ?

Comment: Geralmente os servidores tem uma opção de backup diário, geralmente cobram uns 20 reais ou algo do tipo

Comment: Não é necessário ficar copiando td...

Comment: Caso não queira pagar, e queira continuar mandando tudo pra outra base de dados, porque não faz uma conexão dupla? Tipo, quando ocorrer um insert em um db, ocorre no outro tb?

Comment: Seria só fazer a conexão nos dois no msm arquivo php: 
`$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "senha", "db");
$mysqli2 = new mysqli("host2","user2", "senha2", "db2");

$query = "INSERT INTO minha_tabela ...";

$mysqli->query($query);
$mysqli2->query($query);`

Comment: tenta fazer o dump do banco, mesmo sendo um servidor remoto. Aí basta agendar a execução do dump.... Acho que consegue com isso: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html Só uma observação sobre fazer a conexão com dois bancos: Que gambiarra ein!

Comment: Sincronizar é uma coisa, backup é outra. Backup não pode ser alterado. Sincronização é mera distrubuição física. Se fizer um update errado no original, o sincronizado também estraga. Já vi empresa de "tecnologia" perder dados pq mantinha em sync (e não foi por falta de aviso de que sync não é backup...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi, fazer download mesmo..